# How can i change the row background color for newly added row in jquery

Tags: jquery, html, ajax

After my Ajax form is submitted , i am adding dynamically the new row to table with this code

```
var $var = $('table');
var newRow = "<tr><td> blah </td></tr>"
```

`$var.find('tr:last-child').before(newRow)`

Now i want the background color of that row as light yellow only for 3 seconds then change backto normal

Comment: Are you using jquery-ui?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try using `setTimeout` function:

```
var $newRow = $("<tr class='light'><td>blah<td></tr>");
$var.find('tr:last-child').before($newRow);
setTimeout(function(){
    $('#table tr.light').removeClass('light')
}, 3000)
```

Comment: It changes the color abruptly but i was to slowly fade out the color to white

Answer (score 1):

## *[jsBin demo](http://jsbin.com/upidog/1/edit)*

A nice idea would be to (**without jQuery UI** to animate the BG color) :

- set a custom color to all `td` elements by CSS default
- set a yellow color to all `tr` elements by CSS default
- jQuery   - insert new `tr` with a **hidden** `td` element
- **fadeIn the `td`** element!

**css**

```
table tr{
  display:block;
  background:yellow;
}
table td{
  display:block;
  background:#eee;
}
```

**jQuery**

```
var $var = $('table');

$('button').click(function(){

   var newRow = $("<tr><td> NEW ROW! </td></tr>");
   $var.find('tr:last-child').before(newRow);
   newRow.find('td').hide().fadeTo(3000,1);
  
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a class `new` which has the style and then use `delay` and `queue` to wait for 3 seconds, then remove `new` with `removeClass`.

**JS**

```
var $newRow = "<tr class='new'><td> blah<td></tr>";
$var.find('tr:last-child').before($newRow)
    .delay(3000).queue(function(){
        $('.new').removeClass('new');
    });
```

**CSS**

```
.new {
    background-color: yellow;
}
```

[**demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/xqgcP/1/)

Answer (score 0):

As you say you are using jQueryUI you can use the built in "Highlight" effect, you can see demo of it here http://jqueryui.com/effect/